# How can I organize my chest freezer?

Tags: food, storage, appliances

I've got a chest freezer that's 20.6 x 37.2 x 33.5 inches.

[image]

The freezer tends to stay pretty full to the top because I like to stock up when things are on sale and toss them in there. The problem I'm having is that if I go looking for something specific, I end up having to remove item after item from the freezer as I dig my way to the bottom.

I've considered trying to partition the freezer with some pieces of plywood, but I am not terribly handy with a saw and before I go to the trouble (and find out they just keep falling over in there on me anyway), I was wondering if there are any better options for organizing the freezer and making it easier to find what I'm looking for without having to empty half the freezer every time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The solutions I endorse:**

- Notable methods from [Quick Tips for Organizing the Deep Freezer](http://orgjunkie.com/2014/01/quick-tips-organizing-the-deep-freezer.html)

Using freezer or other storage bags or crates.

[image]
[image]

> Many of you commented about using reusable bags in your chest freezers
> which I thought was just brilliant so that is what I did.  Sorting
> like with like is essential in a freezer so you can keep better track
> of what you have in there.  Reusable bags helps keep your sorted stuff
> separated and available to pull out quickly as needed.  I like it.
> One bag I use for the deer meat and the other for the frozen fruit I
> buy for my smoothies.  Nothing fancy but it gets the job done.

- [preparednessmama.com](http://preparednessmama.com/chest-freezer-organization-ideas/)

> 4. Clearly label each one by making tags for each bag. I made laminated tags that should last a long time and can easily be re-tied
>    and moved when I need to. Plus my family will have no doubt about what
>    is in each one.
> 5. Compartmentalize for easy access. Split your freezer into sections and keep different kinds of food in each area. Meat in one section,
>    precooked meals in another, and fruits and vegetables in a third area.
>    I have two chest freezers so for me that means meat in one freezer and
>    everything else in the other.
> 6. Freeze items flat and stand them up. Space saving at its best! I place my precooked foods in Ziploc bags and freeze them flat.  Then I
>    use the wire bins that come with the freezer and stack them upright
>    with the name of the dish written at the top.

- [InterDesign Classico Basket, Large, Chrome](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0007Q8RTI)- You may have to find some that fit, though.
- [home-storage-solutions-101.com](http://www.home-storage-solutions-101.com/organizing-a-chest-freezer.html)

> *Stackable Baskets Are The Best For Chest Freezers:*
>
> If you don't use any type of storage containers when filling your
> freezer you'll quickly have a jumbled mess.
>
> Baskets are perfect because they keep like items with like, keep
> things from spreading out over more space than they should take, and
> allow stacking.
>
> Stacking is important because you want to be able to easily lift the
> baskets out to move that stuff out of the way to get something lower
> down when you need it, and then easily lay the baskets back to put
> everything away.
>
> *Use Milk Crates As Stackable Baskets For Chest Freezer by Dianne*
>
> My husband and I use milk crates to organize our chest freezer.
>
> We have been doing this for years. The crates stack neatly, are very
> strong, and are easily removed.
>
> Each crate has its own meat. Beef, Chicken, Pork, and Fish.
>
> Vegetables also have a crate.

- [Take Inventory](http://momonamission.me/free-downloads/). This makes sure you know what you have and maybe even make a map about it.
- [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/explore/organize-chest-freezer/) may help you find more ideas.